# Chartjs: Sum of each dataset on top

Tags: javascript, charts

Having this data:

```
const datasets = [
        {
          label: "# of Votes x",
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          fill: true,
        },
        {
          label: "# of Votes y",
          data: [7, 3, 13, 18, 20, 6],
          fill: true,
        },
      ];
```

Is it possible to add at the top of the graph the sum for that column?
Something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

**1. Preprocess your data to get the sum for each column**

```js
let sums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for (let i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
  for (let dataset of datasets) {
    sums[i] += dataset.data[i];
  }
}
```

**2. Create a second x-axis with a new position**

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    // ...
    x2: {
      position: 'top',
      labels: sums
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

let datasets = [
  {
    label: "# of Votes x",
    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    fill: true
  },
  {
    label: "# of Votes y",
    data: [7, 3, 13, 18, 20, 6],
    fill: true
  }
];

let sums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for (let i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
  for (let dataset of datasets) {
    sums[i] += dataset.data[i];
  }
}

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange']
      },
      x2: {
        position: 'top',
        labels: sums
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!, I had to update to version 4 of Chart.js for it to work. Thank you very much.